# MariaDb-failover is running high on CPU and chatty even when there is no traffic

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, amazon-aurora, mariadb-connector-c

We have an API written in scala 2.12.x and Play framework 2.5.x. The API connects to AWS aurora cluster using MariaDb connector/J 2.5.4 as such `jdbc:mysql:aurora://some-aurora-cluster`

Functionally everything works fine except we've noticed high CPU usage even when there is no traffic. A bit of research shows the following:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ top -H

    …
 6373 root      20   0 4644452 990888  21540 S 14.6 12.6   1:15.68 MariaDb-failove
 6374 root      20   0 4644452 990888  21540 S 13.6 12.6   1:16.11 MariaDb-failove
 6305 root      20   0 4644452 990888  21540 S 13.3 12.6   1:14.31 MariaDb-failove
 6375 root      20   0 4644452 990888  21540 S 12.3 12.6   1:14.59 MariaDb-failove
 6372 root      20   0 4644452 990888  21540 S 11.3 12.6   1:15.78 MariaDb-failove
    …
```

The above cmd shows a number of **MariaDb-failover**. I am not sure what it does and why there are multiple of it busy with high CPU usage.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ netstat -a | less

…
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:37446 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:37108 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:37648 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:36934 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:36870 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:37254 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-31.:37902 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-129:mysql TIME_WAIT
…
```

There are a lot of TIME_WAIT. Again this is odd since there was no traffic at the time I executed this cmd.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

      1 established)
      1 Foreign
      1 SYN_SENT
      6 LISTEN
     37 ESTABLISHED
    851 TIME_WAIT
```

There are hundred of TIME_WAIT; and the number is changing every time I executed the cmd.

Does anyone have any insights as to whether this is normal or something I need to worry about?

Please let me know if you have further questions.

==========
More info

```
ps -aux | grep java
```

Got the PID: 2655

```
jstack 2655 > threaddump.log
```

Here is the content (pruned):

```
2020-06-16 16:44:39
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.252-b09 mixed mode):

"MariaDb-failover-5" #276 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b0400b000 nid=0x18e7 waiting on condition [0x00007f4b0c6d6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AuroraProtocol.loop(AuroraProtocol.java:269)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.AuroraListener.reconnectFailedConnection(AuroraListener.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.FailoverLoop.doRun(FailoverLoop.java:84)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.TerminableRunnable.run(TerminableRunnable.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"MariaDb-failover-4" #275 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b0400a000 nid=0x18e6 waiting on condition [0x00007f4afbefd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AuroraProtocol.loop(AuroraProtocol.java:269)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.AuroraListener.reconnectFailedConnection(AuroraListener.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.FailoverLoop.doRun(FailoverLoop.java:84)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.TerminableRunnable.run(TerminableRunnable.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"MariaDb-failover-3" #274 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b04009000 nid=0x18e5 waiting on condition [0x00007f4afbbfa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AuroraProtocol.loop(AuroraProtocol.java:269)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.AuroraListener.reconnectFailedConnection(AuroraListener.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.FailoverLoop.doRun(FailoverLoop.java:84)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.TerminableRunnable.run(TerminableRunnable.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"MariaDb-failover-2" #273 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b04008000 nid=0x18e4 waiting on condition [0x00007f4b0c5d5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AuroraProtocol.loop(AuroraProtocol.java:269)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.AuroraListener.reconnectFailedConnection(AuroraListener.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.FailoverLoop.doRun(FailoverLoop.java:84)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.TerminableRunnable.run(TerminableRunnable.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"MariaDb-failover-1" #265 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b2407e800 nid=0x18a1 waiting on condition [0x00007f4b0c2d4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AuroraProtocol.loop(AuroraProtocol.java:269)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.AuroraListener.reconnectFailedConnection(AuroraListener.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.FailoverLoop.doRun(FailoverLoop.java:84)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.thread.TerminableRunnable.run(TerminableRunnable.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b540db800 nid=0xf37 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b54069000 nid=0xf35 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b5406a800 nid=0xf36 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4b54132800 nid=0xf3e waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 2520
```

PIDs of LWPs in Hex:

```
6373 18e5
6374 18e6
6305 18a1
6375 18e7
6372 18e4
```

==========
More info

Our API has 5 different db configurations - 5 different databases. Each has a connection string as such `jdbc:mysql:aurora://some-aurora-cluster`

Notice that `aurora` mode is used for better experience of fail-over so that it explains the 5 light-weight processes. But they are chatty, resulting in many `TIME_WAIT` and possibly the cause of elevated CPU usage.

Has anyone run into this situation before and how did you mitigate it? I still would like to use `aurora` mode (or something equivalent) so that we don't have to restart the app for when the db fails over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of searching and researching, I finally delved into the MariaDb driver code, particularly in the area where the thread dump had shown, and kept following the code stack.

https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/internal/protocol/AuroraProtocol.java

I've found a reference to a setting `retriesAllDown` which has a default value of 120. Further reading on MariaDb driver knowledge base page, I've also discovered another setting `failoverLoopRetries` which has the same default value of 120.

Here is where you can read more about MariaDb driver settings: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/blob/3bc66153b51aca188afc50ff35a0123f16c099ed/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/util/DefaultOptions.java

For our team and API, we feel comfortable with a value of 12 (10% of the default) and decide to go with that value for both settings, so here is the modified connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql:aurora://some-aurora-cluster?retriesAllDown=12&failoverLoopRetries=12
```

That eases the CPU usage significantly and still maintains the fail-over capability that we need.

Hopefully this answer helps someone down the road. I won't mark it as the answer for my original question until it helps at least 10 other people.